# Is it valid to ask a question about code style/structure?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have a code that is badly disorganized. I wish to receive input from experts regarding how I can make it more understandable for me and for others.

Is that a question suitable for SO or is it 'too vague/not a real question' ?

Answer (score 5):

That is not a suitable question for SO.  It *might* be on topic on Code Review, however be sure to read through their help center to ensure that you form your question in accordance with their guidelines.